# Does Django Template Engine remove the type attribute from script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have a django template that includes a script tag similar to the one below:

```
<script type="text/plain" class="optanon-class">
  //code
</script>
```

The type attribute is important on the script tag, because it prevents the code from executing when the browser initially loads the html. We have a cookie consent process that will run this script according to the user's consent preferences. However, this code is immediately being run without consent. When I view the actual html file that is being utilized on the browser, the script appears as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="optanon-class">
  //code
</script>
```

It seems like during the process of rendering the template, the type attribute is overridden. I can't see anything specific to this within the Django Template Language docs. It does appear that the class attribute is being preserved, but not the type itself.

There's nothing special about the engine or view. We use `TemplateView.as_view(template_name, {context}, name)` in our `url_patterns`. In the settings, the `BACKEND` that we use for templates is the standard `django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates`.

I've tried altering the innerHTML of the script, but the problem here seems to be the type. I'm not sure what I can do to prevent what appears to be an override by the template engine.

Comment: It seems like it would be very weird for Django to do that, because it is not supposed to know or care what the text content of templates means.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this assumption is incorrect. The attribute change is actually associated with the consent process.